# How to get skip level manager details in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've recently appeared for a Sql assessment wherein I was asked to find the skip level managers for all the employees. 
 Consider the input `emp` table as below -

```
+-----+-----+
|Empid|Mgrid|
+-----+-----+
|1    |2    |
|2    |3    |
|3    |4    |
|4    |5    |
|5    |6    |
|6    |7    |
|7    |8    |
|8    |null |
+-----+-----+
```

***Expected Output -***

```
+-----+-----+
|Empid|Mgrid|
+-----+-----+
|1    |3    |
|2    |4    |
|3    |5    |
|4    |6    |
|5    |7    |
|6    |8    |
|7    |8    |
|8    |null |
+-----+-----+
```

So for eg - for `empid = 1` his skip-level manager should be 3. 
I tried using the below query but it is not working -

```
Select
  a.Empid,
  b.Mgrid as SkipLevelMgr
from
  emp a
  inner join (
    select
      empid,
      mgrid
    from
      emp
  ) b on b.mgrid > a.mgrid
```

Please help!

Comment: I'd expect (7, null), instead of (7,8).

Comment: Also, no need for a subquery, a simple self join will do fine.

Comment: Why that additional select? `select ... from emp a join emp b` should just be as fine. About `on` condition: It looks to me as if `a.mgrid` should equal `b.empid` provided I understood your question right...

Comment: @jarlh - It will be (7,8) only. Reason being no one is above 8 (consider him as CEO of an organization)

Comment: @Aconcagua - What about the second last empid?

Comment: Suppose it needs special handling. You might have previous query and `union` it with another one selecting this very last special case only. `select empid, mgrid from emp where mgrid = select max(mgrid) from emp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from a query that does *most* of the job you want:

```
SELECT a.empid, b.mgrid FROM emp a JOIN emp b
    ON a.mgrid = b.empid AND b.mgrid NOT NULL
```

you can append the yet missing entries via a union. Before doing so note that I've already filtered out the `7|null` entries you otherwise would have gotten with the additional condition above. Now adding those members that are yet missing, the top level managers and those directly below:

```
UNION
SELECT empid, mgrid FROM emp
    WHERE mgrid = (SELECT MAX(mgrid) FROM emp) OR mgrid IS NULL
```

Note that the query is untested, if you find a bug please fix yourself (and you might want to add some ordering which I leave to you, too).

Answer (score 3):

..[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cad3c5ff41371d9e61d229c673d9ef0b)..

```
with emp
as
(
select *
from 
(
values (1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(6,7),(7,8),(8,null)
) as em(empid,mgrid)
)
select e.empid, isnull(m.mgrid, e.mgrid) as skipmgr
from emp as e
left join emp as m on e.mgrid = m.empid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the join condition i.e `b.Mgrid > a.Mgrid` to `a.Mgrid = b.Empid`. Also, you don't need to write sub-query.

Try this:

```
SELECT A.Empid
    ,B.Mgrid AS SkipLevelMgr
FROM emp A
LEFT JOIN emp B
ON A.Mgrid = B.Empid
```

Comment: This will not work for (7,8). Reason being no one is above 8 (consider him as CEO of an organization)

Comment: And you need an outer join to keep the row (8, null),

Comment: @dexter48 Updated query with LEFT JOIN